# OpenGL-How do I draw randomly non-overlapping circle

Tags: c++, opengl, random

I've already draw few random placed circle, but I want different numbers of circles every time I run the program. So the question really is how do I call a function in random times?

I also need them to have convex and concave effects but unable to arrange them to random circles.

Finally, I need circles not to overlap, how do I do that?

Below is my partial code so far.

```
void circle(){
    double r=50;
    int dx, dy;
    dx=rand()%350;
    dy=rand()%250;
    glLineWidth(1);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    double i=1.0;
    double j=0.0;
    for (double y=r; y>=-r; y=y-1) {
        i=i-0.01;
        j=j+0.01;
        //glColor3f(i, i, i);
        glColor3f(j, j, j);
        glVertex2f(-sqrt(r*r-y*y)+dx, y+dy);
        glVertex2f(sqrt(r*r-y*y)+dx, y+dy);
    }


    glEnd();

}

void display(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    circle();
    circle();
    circle();


    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## The simple approach

It is enough to pick a random number and iterate. This can cause the circles to overlap.

```
int min_circles = 10;
int max_circles = 100;

int amount = min_circles + rand()%(max_circles-min_circles+1);

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) 
  circle();
```

## Non overlapping

This is not a trivial matter and has been an interesting research topic. You can have several approaches to this problem for example:

#### Naïve Generation

Store all previously added circle positions and if you try to add a new one just do a check with the previous for overlapping. If it overlaps choose another position. If it fails several times in a row then stop.

#### Easing

You can also consider treating all circles as a system of points connected with springs and iterate a few times so that the springs will repel the circles from each other thus conforming to the non-overlapping rule.

#### Poisson Disk Sampling

You can read up on implementing **Poisson Disk Sampling** on the internet. The algorithm generates a uniform random distribution of points on a plane so that they are at certain distance from each other. Then just use these points as centers of circles.

Answer (score 0):

how do I call a function in random times?

that one way of doing it:

```
if (rand() % someNumber == 0)
 callFunc();
```

I also need them to have convex and concave effects but unable to arrange them to random circles.
 i didnt understand what you mean.

Finally, I need circles not to overlap, how do I do that?

first you need to creaye circles in a structure, and store them in a collection. assume you the structure like that:

```
struct Circle {
 float x, y, raduis;
}
```

and a collection like that:

```
std::vector<Circle> circles;
```

then the creation may look like that:

```
Circle c;
do {
 bool canExit = true;
 c.x = rand()*350;
 c.y = rand()*250;
 c.radius = 50;

 for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
  float dx = (circles[i].x - c.x);
  float dy = (circles[i].y - c.y);
  floar radii = circles[i].radius + c.radius;
  if (dx*dx + dy*dy < (radii*radii) ) {
   canExit = false;
   break;
  }
 }

while(canExit == false);

circles.push_back(c);
```

of cours thats only may way, hope it works for you, and good luck.